# How to make ntpd synchronized immediately after reboot?

Tags: linux, ntp

My application must run on a server with time synchronized. In order to do that I installed `ntpd` and I check the return value of `ntpstat`. It appears that it takes a very long time to get a zero return value from `ntpstat`, especially after reboot. Why does it take `ntpd` such a long period to get synchronized and how can I make it happen few seconds after reboot?

Comment: Run `ntpdate <server>` just before starting up `ntpd`. This is usually in the `init` script of `ntpd`. It's possible yours don't have it. Needless to say, the network should also be up when `ntpdate` is executed.

Comment: What is the `init` script of `ntpd`? I installed it using yum and the only file that looks like what you say is `/etc/ntp.conf` but it doesn't have start and stop sections So I'm not sure in which file I need to add the command you suggested

Comment: Different distributions of Linux use different init scripts, some even use `systemd`. You can find the init script by running `rpm -ql ntp` and it will show all the files that the package owns. In my Linux it is `/etc/init.d/ntpd` and `/etc/init.d/ntpdate`. And if you are using `lsb` scripts, `chkconfig --list ntpd` and `chkconfig --list ntpdate` will show if both of them are set to auto start. If you are using `systemd`, then `systemd -a | grep ntp` will show if they are active/inactive/enabled/disabled.

Comment: OK, I'm using systemd and I found the init files under `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` I'm still not sure exactly how but I understand your answer and I understand where I should add it. If you write your response as an answer I'll be able to accept it (if it will work).

Comment: FYI: instead of rolling your own solution of checking for time sync you can just use `ntp-wait` which is provided in the ntp refence implementation. `apropos ntp-wait: ntp-wait - Wait for ntpd to stabilize the system clock`. This is also more portable than your ntpstat solution because it does not rely on any vendor provided utils like `ntpstat.`

Comment: Offtopic, unless this is part of a larger script or something like that. Belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as it was found - start up script invokes ntpd.service, which waiting for `ntpdate.service` to run.
While ntpdate isn't service, but application - it running once via nice wrapper script, located at `/usr/libexec/ntpdate-wrapper` , which is checking conditions, where one of them - if there any servers, described at `/etc/ntp/step-tickers` . If yes - it invokes ntpdate with those servers, which is set up by default by fedora installer to 0.fedoratime.smth.ininternet , that is not fits closed environment.

So there 3 choices:
 1. Modify ntpdate wrapper, that he will look first for `ntp.conf`
 2. Modify `/etc/ntp/step-tickers` to have your own ntp server
 3. Modify `ntpdate.service` to not invoke wrapper, but just invoke command with adding/replacing lines in its configuration:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ntpd -q -g -x
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

Answer (score 3):

To synchronize `ntp` immediately after reboot, `ntpdate` has to run before `ntpd`.

To do this in systemd, you can run

`systemctl -a | grep ntp`

to see if ntpdate is enabled. To enable it is just run

`systemctl enable ntpdate`

For Linuxes that use `lsb` scripts, you can enable `ntpdate` via `chkconfig`.

`chkconfig ntpdate on`

Comment: Please see my answer to a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779584/why-ntpd-service-is-not-started-automatically-after-reboot
So it appears that you don't need to run `ntpdate` but just to make sure that ntpd.service is running after boot. I will accept your answer since it helped to find the root cause of this problem.

Comment: Now I have a full answer to the problem, let me first say that indeed you need to call `ntpdate` the problem is that the server which `ntpd` uses for synch and the server which `ntpdate.service` (`/usr/libexec/ntpdate-wrapper`) uses are not the same. So if you changed the server in `/etc/ntp.conf` you need also to change the server which is in `/etc/ntp/step-tickers`.

Answer (score 0):

In
2021-05-07-raspios-buster-armhf-lite

there is no ntp binary and no ntpd.

I have an installation script that needs to run after the first boot. I also had these synchronization problems. To make sure that my installation script waits for time sync I did this:

```
STATE="no_time_sync"

while [ $STATE != "yes" ]; do
        # Check the current ntp sync status
        STATE=$(timedatectl status | grep "System clock synchronized" | awk '{print $4}')

        # Sleep for 3 seconds and wait for ntp sync
        sleep 3

done

echo "System clock synchronized"
```

Works like a charm for me:

```
May 07 16:00:34 raspberrypi setup[534]: Waiting for internet connection
May 07 16:00:39 raspberrypi setup[534]: Internet connection
Nov 05 08:32:32 raspberrypi setup[534]: System clock synchronized
```

At least in this Raspbian version, I'm not quite sure if the synchronization can be boosted anyhow. It already takes some time to setup the ethernet interface in order to reach out into the internet. And the ntp service is already enabled by default. I could decrease my sleep duration during my loops, though. Waiting for internet and waiting for clock sync have sleep times of 3 seconds. ;)