# Why ntpd service is not started automatically after reboot?

Tags: linux, ntp, systemd

After I installed `ntpd` via `yum` I run the command `systemctl enable ntpd.service` and rebooted the computer. After I got the shell prompt I run `systemctl -a | grep ntp` and I got `ntpd.service loaded inactive dead`. If I start it manually using  `systemctl start ntpd.service` it works fine. Why is that? How can I ensure the `ntpd.service` will be up and running after reboot?

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be an issue with fedora, there is a service named "chrony" which prevents ntpd service to start after boot. After removing chrony with `yum`, ntpd service is started after boot. For more details you can check [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=821813).

UPDATE: You can also disable the `chronyd` that runs on port 123 and then ntpd will start:

```
sudo systemctl disable chronyd
sudo systemctl start ntpd
```

Comment: I also faced this issue using CentOS 7.